# Certain things only work when a breakpoint is hit

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, debugging

I have a WPF application that does stuff like use the standard `Settings.Default` to persist settings and start a static and SignalR webserver.

After a large refactoring I started hitting a very strange condition. Those two things work *when I put a breakpoint on* `Settings.Default.Save()` or in my SignalR Hub constructor respectively. However, if I just let the application run (in Debug mode) that code does not run.

Specifically, unless I have a breakpoint on the `Settings.Default.Save()` they do not get persisted.

Specifically - I put a `Console.WriteLine` inside my hub constructor. Unless I have a breakpoint inside the constructor (anywhere seems to work), it does not get logged.

The only thing I can think of is some sort of thread permission issue - but in the SignalR hub case at least it should all be firing from the main UI thread. I've also tried putting my settings save inside `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` to no effect.

What else can it be?

Comment: Just curious if you put a Thread.Sleep(1000) line in front of the Settings.Default.Save() function to see if it has the same effect as the breakpoint.  I just put 1 second for example, it may take longer.  I've had similar conditions that usually pointed back to another object not being completely initialized.  I then went on to create MansualResetEvent(s) and waited for them to get set per the object(s) in question that needed to finish initialization.

Comment: @DavidGlass the entire thing was being debounced but that might be worth checking